# PHP - Change position of echoed text from custom login page

Tags: php

I'm using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>TechBuzz-Incredible Saurav</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<?php
session_start();
if (ISSET($_GET['login'])) {
    if ($_POST ['password'] ==  'iamgreat' ) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        header("Location:redirect.php");
        exit;
    } 
else echo "Wrong details" ;     
}
?>
<body bgcolor="black">
                 <!-----start-main---->
                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="images/mem2.jpg" alt=""/>

                    </div>

                <form action= "?login=1" method="post">
                <font face="comic sans ms" color=grey size="5px"> <b> Please Login to TechBuzz: </b> </font><br><br>

                    <li>
                        <input type="password" name="password""><a href="#" class=" icon lock" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="p-container">
                                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked><i></i>Remember Me</label>
                                <input type="submit" />
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div>
        </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this and enter an incorrect password, it says "Wrong details" on the top of the page. I want to change the position of this `else echo "Wrong details";`. Can anyone help me in this? I'm a beginner.

How can I set 2 passwords?

Comment: First, move that block of code to the very top. You have to have the `header()` function run before anything outputs to the page.

Comment: i think you have not given submit button name...

Comment: why are you using this `onfocus="this.value = '';"` And  this `onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}"` and do this in your php code `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Second, do `else $error = true;` instead of the `echo`. Then put down the page somewhere you want the message to display `if(isset($error)) echo 'Wrong details';` Something like that.

Comment: @Vicky It does'nt matter why I used this. I just want to know how I can make "wrong details" appear on the bottom of the page

Comment: Just follow this link it will help you to understand and built something more meaningful http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Comment: @Franky check the code once again.

Comment: @Rasclatt Can you please edit the code and show here?

Comment: @IncredibleSaurav its not an standard and not a good approach follow the link i have sent you and try to run the code by your self make use of `print_r()` && `echo` to identify the exact location of problem.

Comment: @Franky, I don't want to make this complicated. I don't want to create different files for session or increase the length of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really is a pretty simple task. All you need to do is set a variable and echo it down below.

Use `<?php echo $error; ?>` wherever you want to echo the error. The else statement sets a value to $error; otherwise it is a blank string, and will therefore show nothing even when echoed.

Also, you should move the php to the top of the page. Here is the full code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$error = ""; // set blank string to start with

if (isset($_GET['login'])) {

    if ($_POST['password'] == 'iamgreat') {

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        header("Location:redirect.php");
        exit;

    }
    else $error = "<div style='color: red;'>Wrong Details</div>";

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>TechBuzz-Incredible Saurav</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
                 <!-----start-main---->
                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="images/mem2.jpg" alt=""/>

                    </div>

                <form action= "?login=1" method="post">
                <font face="comic sans ms" color=grey size="5px"> <b> Please Login to TechBuzz: </b> </font><br><br>

<?php echo $error; ?>

                    <li>
                        <input type="password" name="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}"><a href="#" class=" icon lock" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="p-container">
                                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked><i></i>Remember Me</label>
                                <input type="submit" />
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div>
        </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments. Move `header()` et al up to top and then set a variable such as `$error`. Do a check later down the page and `echo` where you want:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    if($_POST['password'] ==  'iamgreat' ) {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
            header("Location:redirect.php");
            exit;
        } 
    // You don't really need an else here
    // seeings as it will either exit or error
    $error = true;     
} ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<title>TechBuzz-Incredible Saurav</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<!-----start-main---->
    <div class="login-form">
        <div class="head">
            <img src="images/mem2.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <!-- Here you can either echo the text, or show a block of html:
        Option 1
        <?php if(isset($error)) echo "Wrong details"; ?>
        -->
        <!-- Option 2 -->
        <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
        <h2>Wrong details</h2><?php } ?>
        <form action="?login=1" method="post">
            <font face="comic sans ms" color=grey size="5px"><b>Please Login to TechBuzz: </b></font><br><br>
            <!-- You have no <ul> or <ol> -->
                <li><input type="password" name="password""><a href="#" class=" icon lock" /></a></li>
                <div class="p-container">
                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked><i></i>Remember Me</label>
                <input type="submit" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen your comment that you need to appear that error at bottom of page. I am adding that error before submit button & after password field. So that user can easily see the error near to button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>TechBuzz-Incredible Saurav</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<?php
session_start();
if (ISSET($_GET['login'])) {
    if ($_POST ['password'] ==  'iamgreat' ) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        header("Location:redirect.php");
        exit;
    } 
else $msg="Wrong details" ;     
}
?>
<body bgcolor="black">
                 <!-----start-main---->
                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="images/mem2.jpg" alt=""/>

                    </div>

                <form action= "?login=1" method="post">
                <font face="comic sans ms" color=grey size="5px"> <b> Please Login to TechBuzz: </b> </font><br><br>

                    <li>
                        <input type="password" name="password""><a href="#" class=" icon lock" /></a>
                    </li><br /> <font size="3" color="red"><?php echo $msg; ?></font>
                    <div class="p-container">
                                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked><i></i>Remember Me</label>
                                <input type="submit" />
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div>
        </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You missed the fact that you can not put the `header()` where you have it. That will give a header output error.

Comment: i didnt get you.. as he said that he want to display error message at bottom. I made correct. Can i know the issue? i think `header()` present at starting is correct. Can i know the details?

Comment: If you notice in the PHP manual, the `header()` must come before output to the browser or the header will draw an error and (may) not redirect. Though your answer about the message is correct, you fail to address that issue. For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: But user is not supposed to see that message "Wrong details" if he gives correct details. So if user gives correct details main aim is to redirect user to other script. So no matter of placing `header()` . If user gives wrong details, he will be shown that message

Comment: Someone asks, "Why is my car not working?" As you say, "You need to turn the key in the ignition" you notice a tire is missing. Your argument is it's not your responsibility to let that person know they are also missing a tire because they asked about why the car doesn't turn on? In this case the tire is not missing, it's in the back seat....but it doesn't matter because regardless of where the tire is, the car will turn on, so job well-done!

Answer (score 0):

in following answer i'll show you a simple javascript way but if you use JQUERY then it is very simple for you to handle thing like this------learn jquery that will help you for advance web development.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>  
        <head>
            <title>TechBuzz-Incredible Saurav</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php
         session_start();
         if (ISSET($_GET['login'])) {
             if ($_POST ['password'] ==  'iamgreat' ) {
                 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                 header("Location:redirect.php");
                 exit;
             } 
         else echo "<script>document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "visible";</script>" ;     
         }
        ?>
        </head>

        <body bgcolor="black">
                         <!-----start-main---->
                        <div class="login-form">
                            <div class="head">
                                <img src="images/mem2.jpg" alt=""/>

                            </div>
<!-----Put this DIV where you want to show message---->
                        <div id="errorMsg" style="display:none">Wrong Details</div>
                        <form action= "?login=1" method="post">
                        <font face="comic sans ms" color=grey size="5px"> <b> Please Login to TechBuzz: </b> </font><br><br>

                            <li>
                                <input type="password" name="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}"><a href="#" class=" icon lock" /></a>
                            </li>
                            <div class="p-container">
                                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked><i></i>Remember Me</label>
                                        <input type="submit" />
                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                            </div>
                </form>
                    </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: How can i set 2 passwords? @Rasclatt

Comment: i didn'e get you what you mean by two password